# why do i see the message "do_IRQ: 5.33 No irq handler for vector" on my dell xps 15 9550?

Tags: linux, kernel, linux-kernel, irq

Every time I suspend/unsuspend my laptop (Dell XPS 15 9550) I see this kernel log:

```
Message from syslogd@cruz-XPS-15-9550 at Sep 14 07:58:31 ...
 kernel:[  725.565407] do_IRQ: 5.33 No irq handler for vector
```

My CPU is Intel i7-6700HQ and I'm with both graphic cards this error happens (intel graphic card or NVidia graphic card).

I've already tried to use a kernel parameter `pci=nomsi` (this one almost render unusable my machine) and `apic=verbose` didn't add much info to `dmesg` output.

With Ubuntu 20.10 (kernel 5.8.0-44-generic) the problem has migrated to:

```
Message from syslogd@cruz-XPS-15-9550 at Mar  9 16:49:45 ...
 kernel:[23057.190296] __common_interrupt: 5.33 No irq handler for vector
```

According to the [kernel source](https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/arch/x86/kernel/irq.c#L255), 5.33 means CPU 5, IRQ 33.

### Flash news!!

On Ubuntu 20.10 something fixed this problem a couple of days ago!

Comment: Judging from [this thread](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=256227&p=3), it seems some drivers need updating. I have the same problem but haven't tried updating drivers.

Comment: Thanks. I have 5.4.0-70-generic and seems latest Stable kernel for Ubuntu 20.04 is 5.4.0-72.80, so will have to wait.